# How to set onclick property to dynamically generated input box

Tags: javascript, dom

Initially I have a table with a certain number of rows and some columns containing `input` controls with click event handlers.

When I add rows dynamically into the table, how could I set the onclick property to the `input` controls of the dynamically generated rows?

Comment: You just assign the function to the property, just like with normal objects. What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'button';
cell.appendChild(input);
input.onclick = function () {
   alert('Clicked!');
};
```

Here is an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J3zxB/).

Comment: Thanks @Minko, that works just fine. Earlier i made a mistake by directly assigning my inbuilt function to input.onclick.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions

1. you are using jquery
2. some jquery block on some condition is adding some more element.

The jquery [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and better [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functions help you with that.

```
$('input.yourClass').live('click', function(e) {
  // your code
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('click', 'yourClass', function(e) {
// your code
});
```

should do the trick.

If you are not using jquery, life can be a tad difficult!

Comment: 1. Question is not tagged JQuery. 2. Life is not that difficult unless you complicate things. I.e: f*ck up. ;)

Comment: thanks @Arindam for yours help, right now i am not using Jquery but latter on i will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the input elements in your document and manipulate them, using this code:

```
for (a in each=document.getElementsByTagName('input')) { 
console.log(each[a])
) }
```